# Numpy signed maximum magnitude of cumsum along an axis

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, cumsum

I have a numpy array `a`, `a.shape=(17,90,144)`. I want to find the maximum magnitude of each column of `cumsum(a, axis=0)`, but retaining the original sign. In other words, if for a given column `a[:,j,i]` the largest magnitude of `cumsum` corresponds to a negative value, I want to retain the minus sign.

The code `np.amax(np.abs(a.cumsum(axis=0)))` gets me the magnitude, but doesn't retain the sign. Using `np.argmax` instead will get me the indices I need, which I can then plug into the original `cumsum` array. But I can't find a good way to do so.

The following code works, but is dirty and really slow:

```
max_mag_signed = np.zeros((90,144))
indices = np.argmax(np.abs(a.cumsum(axis=0)), axis=0)
for j in range(90):
    for i in range(144):
        max_mag_signed[j,i] = a.cumsum(axis=0)[indices[j,i],j,i]
```

There must be a cleaner, faster way to do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't find any alternatives to `argmax` but at least you can fasten that with a more vectorized approach:

```
# store the cumsum, since it's used multiple times
cum_a = a.cumsum(axis=0)

# find the indices as before
indices = np.argmax(abs(cum_a), axis=0)

# construct the indices for the second and third dimensions
y, z = np.indices(indices.shape)

# get the values with np indexing
max_mag_signed = cum_a[indices, y, z]
```

Comment: Thanks -- huge speedup. I wasn't familiar with the `np.indices` function. For code readability then I guess I should change the name of my `indices` variable.

Comment: Just had a thought: as an alternative, you could possibly do it (in pseudo code) by taking `aplus=np.amax(np.cumsum(a, axis=0), axis=0)` and `aminus=np.amax(np.cumsum(-1*a, axis=0), axis=0)`, taking the larger magnitude at each point, and then flipping the sign of those values that came from `aminus`? But this is getting messy - the solution by Avaris is sufficiently clean and fast already.